# Drag and Drop Libgdx, without a Target

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, libgdx

Im trying to implement the Drag And Drop method/class in libgdx, but what´s different for me is that I dont have a "Target" to drop my actor. I simply want to drag it around all over the screen. I haven´t really got any further than this.

```
dd = new DragAndDrop();
            dd.addSource(new Source(stoneImage){


                @Override
                public Payload dragStart(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
                    Payload payload = new Payload();
                    payload.setObject("some payload");
                    payload.setDragActor(stoneImage);
                    return payload;

                }
            });
```

Here I set the Image as an actor:

```
stageMove.addActor(stoneImage);
```

At the moment it won´t move when I try to drag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you 2 easy ways to solve your problem.

1) Add a DragListener to your actor:

```
actor.addListener(new DragListener() {
    public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
        actor.moveBy(x - actor.getWidth() / 2, y - actor.getHeight() / 2);
    }
});
```

2) Create a generic actor which size is filled to the stage, and use it as the target actor.

Comment: Thanks! I´ll go with your first method. Though, I believe I have to make my Image to an Actor somehow? Right now I only do stoneImage.addListener etc.. And that isn´t doing it.

Comment: I encore you to use an Scene2d with a Stage and multiple actors, more info here. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d